# Sqlalchemy core - Using func.sum across a union query

Tags: python, function, sqlalchemy, sum, union

I am trying to work out how to sum the results of the union_all select. I can use the sum function on individual selects but not the union of them.

```
union_all(
    select([first.c.amount]).
        where(first.c.player_id == player_id).

    select([second.c.amount]).
        where(second.c.player_id == player_id).

    select([third.c.amount]).
        where(third.c.player_id == player_id).

    select([fourth.c.amount]).
        where(fourth.c.player_id == player_id).
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the (alias of the) union as a selectable and just select the sum of amount:

```
In [15]: u = union_all(
    ...:     select([first.c.amount]).
    ...:         where(first.c.player_id == player_id),
    ...: 
    ...:     select([second.c.amount]).
    ...:         where(second.c.player_id == player_id),
    ...: 
    ...:     select([third.c.amount]).
    ...:         where(third.c.player_id == player_id),
    ...: 
    ...:     select([fourth.c.amount]).
    ...:         where(fourth.c.player_id == player_id)
    ...: ).alias()

In [16]: stmt = func.sum(u.c.amount).select()

In [17]: print(stmt)
SELECT sum(anon_1.amount) AS sum_1 
FROM (SELECT first.amount AS amount 
FROM first 
WHERE first.player_id = :player_id_1 UNION ALL SELECT second.amount AS amount 
FROM second 
WHERE second.player_id = :player_id_2 UNION ALL SELECT third.amount AS amount 
FROM third 
WHERE third.player_id = :player_id_3 UNION ALL SELECT fourth.amount AS amount 
FROM fourth 
WHERE fourth.player_id = :player_id_4) AS anon_1
```